# Getting QuantityStrings to pick up on Zeros

Tags: android

I am using **Quantity Strings** to display the values chosen in **Number Pickers** that are in my **custom Dialog**.
 Since my **Number Pickers** are the hours and minutes that I want to do a certain activity, the values chosen appear in a **textview** below the pickers.

On the hour picker, when I choose **0** initially, it reacts as defined in the **XML file** for a "**zero**" value, but subsequently, after having chosen other values for the hours, and then I choose **0** for the hours, it treats my choice as "**other**", not as "**zero**". Please advise!

My res/values/strings.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <plurals name="hour_picker">
        <item quantity="zero">"You want to walk for  "</item>
        <item quantity="one">"You want to walk for %1$d hour and  "</item>
        <item quantity="other">"You want to walk for %1$d hours and "</item>
    </plurals>
    <plurals name="minute_picker">
        <item quantity="one"> %1$d minute</item>
        <item quantity="other"> %1$d minutes</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

The .java file is as follows:

```
  public class SelectDurationDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {

    NumberPicker  hour_picker,minute_picker;
    TextView hour_txt,minute_txt;
...
@Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int i1) {

        switch (numberPicker.getId()){
            case R.id.numberPicker1:
                hour_txt.setText(String.format(getResources().getQuantityString((R.plurals.hour_picker),i1),i1));
                break;
            case R.id.numberPicker2:
                minute_txt.setText(String.format(getResources().getQuantityString((R.plurals.minute_picker),i1),i1));
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals:

The selection of which string to use is made solely based on grammatical necessity. In English, a string for zero will be ignored even if the quantity is 0, because 0 isn't grammatically different from 2, or any other number except 1 ("zero books", "one book", "two books", and so on). Conversely, in Korean only the other string will ever be used.

Don't be misled either by the fact that, say, two sounds like it could only apply to the quantity 2: a language may require that 2, 12, 102 (and so on) are all treated like one another but differently to other quantities. Rely on your translator to know what distinctions their language actually insists upon.

Comment: If it was only based on grammatical necessity, why did it recognize zero initially?

Comment: My mistake, it never recognized "zero" initially, I deleted the"zero" line and got the same result.